# Unable to create In-App Product, As the Create Option is Disabled

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscription

I am working on a iOS app, Its first Version is "Ready For Sale". Now on the Second version, we want to use In-App Purchase. Now the App is in "Developer Rejected" state. When I am trying to create a new Product for In-App Purchase by going to "Features->In-App Purchase" and click the + button the Create Option is disabled. [You can see the Disable create button the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuVLR.png)

Is there may anything wrong with my process. Please guide me what should I do to make it working :)

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you have not filled out the legal agreements for sales in iTunes Connect. Unfortunately, it is not well documented. You need to be logged into the account with the `Legal` permission in iTunes Connect. Then go to `Agreements, Tax, and Banking`. Then you need to create and fill out the `Paid Applications` contract which will include putting in your banking and tax info. Once you do that, the In App Purchase menu will have items in it.